# Can I add new credit card and deactivate old credit card using Authorize.net

Tags: credit-card, authorize.net

I went through the Authorize.net documentation, there are calls to create new customer profile, update customer profile (update billing and card info) but I did not see a call to add new card and deactivate old card.

Did someone used add card on Authorize.net?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A customer profile can hold up to 10 payment and shipping address profiles.  Use [Create a Customer Payment Profile](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#customer-profiles-create-customer-payment-profile) and [Delete a Customer Payment Profile](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#customer-profiles-delete-customer-profile) respectively.